# Calculating residues of singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

- I'm trying to calculate the residues of
  $\displaystyle\frac{z^{1/2}\log\left(z\right)}{\left(\,1 + z\,\right)^{2}}$ at its singularities.
- I've so far got that there is a pole of order $2$ at $z = -1$ and the residue at this point is $\pi/2 -\mathrm{i}$ but my final answer for the question ( a contour integral ) is not correct and also Wolfram says that this function has no poles so I'm a bit confused as to where I went wrong.

Comment: The pole is at $-1$ rather than at $1$, provided one uses branches of the square root and the logarithm that are defined there. Note that the residue depends on the chosen branches then. Wolfram probably uses the principal branches, which are defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ t \in \mathbb{R} : t \leqslant 0\}$, and so omit the potential pole from the domain of definition.

Comment: Apologies  I meant $z=-1$,  and both branches I'm using take values $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$

Comment: Please, shows explicitly the integral you want to evaluate.

Comment: So $f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ t \in \mathbb{R} : t \geqslant 0\}$, with its only pole at $-1$. One can probably tell Wolfram Alpha to use these branches, so that it can compute the residue. What contour integral are you trying to evaluate?

Comment: The integral of the above function from $0$ to $\infty$ using a keyhole contour with a cut on the positive real axis

Comment: Since $$\lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} \log (x - i\varepsilon) = \log x + 2\pi i\,,$$ the integral over the keyhole contour comes out as $$2\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\,\log x}{(1+x)^2}\,dx +2\pi i \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{(1+x)^2}\,dx\,.$$ Use the same contour to evaluate $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{(1+x)^2}\,dx$.

Comment: Would I not need the residue to work the final answer out?

Comment: Yes (well, there are other ways than the residue theorem …), you need the residue of both functions at $-1$ to evaluate the integral(s).

Answer (score 1):

Despite you may find $z=-1$ as second order pole of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}$, it's not an isolated singularity of whole function because of $\log(z)$. The singularities of $\log(z)$ are on $z\leq0$ and residue can't be defined as well.

Comment: so does that mean the residue for this function doesnt exist?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't exist in any point since the only points probable to be singularity/ies is z=1.

Comment: Why would z=1 even be a probable singularity?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake! I mean z=-1.....